# How can '/e' regex expression be misused on a PHP code snippet running on my server?

Tags: php, linux, security

I'm learning about linux systems, and I've read that '/e' is deprecated, but I'm using a machine with PHP 5.3 and I want to learn how this code could be misused to execute different commands. How can I use this code to execute external commands?

```html
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
        function y($m)
        {
                $m = preg_replace("/\./", " x ", $m);
                $m = preg_replace("/@/", " y", $m);
                return $m;
        }

        function x($y, $z)
        {
                $a = file_get_contents($y);
                $a = preg_replace("/(\[x (.*)\])/e", "y(\"\\2\")", $a);
                $a = preg_replace("/\[/", "(", $a);
                $a = preg_replace("/\]/", ")", $a);
                return $a;
        }
        $r = x($argv[1], $argv[2]);
        print $r;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the results found that the vulnerable code is here:

```
$a = preg_replace("/(\[x (.*)\])/e", "y(\"\\2\")", $a);
```

A possible remote code execution (RCE) could be achieved by executing something similar to this:

```
./script.php path/to/malicious_file.txt
```

Being this the content of the malicious file

```
[x {${system('id')}}]
```

##### The /e Modifier

The /e modifier in preg_replace is used to evaluate the replacement string as PHP code. This means that whatever is being replaced can be executed as code on the server. This feature is inherently dangerous because it can execute arbitrary PHP code if an attacker can control the input.

##### The Vulnerable Pattern

The pattern "/([x (.*)])/e" is designed to match strings that start with [x and end with ]. Whatever is between these brackets is captured by the (.*), which is then passed to the y() function for further processing.

##### The Replacement Execution

The replacement part "y("\2")" indicates that the captured group (.*) (denoted by \2) is passed to the y() function as an argument. Because of the /e modifier, this is not just a simple function call; the string that results from y("\2") is executed as PHP code.

##### The Exploit

An attacker can exploit this by crafting input that, when processed by this preg_replace statement, results in executing arbitrary PHP code. The provided malicious file content [x {${system('id')}}] demonstrates this:
The pattern matches [x {${system('id')}}].
The captured group {${system('id')}} is passed to the y() function.
Due to the /e modifier, the PHP code within the captured group {${system('id')}} is executed. In this case, it's a system('id') call, which executes the Unix id command, showing the user and group ID.

##### Important Notes

**Do Not Execute Unknown or Untrusted Code**: Experimenting with and learning from vulnerabilities like this is valuable for educational purposes or security research, within a safe and controlled environment. Never execute untrusted code on live, production, or sensitive systems.
**Update and Secure Your Systems**: PHP 5.3 is outdated and no longer supported. Using outdated software exposes you to numerous security vulnerabilities and risks. Always use up-to-date software versions and apply security best practices to protect your systems.